# How do I change order of list menu toolbar menus in SharePoint

Tags: list, sharepoint, menu, customization

I need to add custom menu to list menu toolbar. I wrote `elements.xml` as shown below:

```
<CustomAction
   Id="SiteActionsToolbar"
   RegistrationType="ContentType"
   RegistrationId="0x01"
   Location="ViewToolbar"
   Title="Upload"
   Sequence="0"
   Description="Upload file ti file system">
   <UrlAction Url="SitePages/UploadFile.aspx?ListId={ListId}"/>
</CustomAction>
```

My custom menu appears and works fine.
But the requirement is set displaying order of  this menu after "new" menu before "action" menu.

Is it possible to do this in sharepoint without using Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the location using below tags:

> <CommandUIExtension><CommandUIDefinitions>
>           <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.**New**.Controls._children">...

You can change the location by replacing the "New" with your section.

> General entries will be "New", "Manage", "copies", "workflows"

The line **Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children** says to sharepoint in which section to place your custom button.

Comment: It seems working for sharepoint 2010, but i need for sharepoint 2007